# Zooming only an image in mobile Safari

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari, zooming

I'm looking to see if anyone has experience with this. I'm a developer first and a designer second, so this is really not my strongest suit.

I have a project I'm working on where the goal is to get image and text side-by-side in landscape mode on the iPhone. I'd like to be able to zoom in on the image using a pinch like normal, but **not** zoom in on the text as well while that is happening. I don't know if this is even possible or what kind of hacks it would take to get it working.

If someone thinks this is bad in general from a UI perspective, I am open to suggestions.

I have considered keeping two copies of the image (low and high res) and then swapping them out inside of div with an `overflow: scroll;` so users can get a zoomed version and then scroll around. It doesn't give you the full effect of zooming, but it might accomplish a similar goal. I don't know if this would work either.

If anyone has suggestions or experience on the subject, please chime in. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To do this in mobile safari you would probably have to use javascript. Theres a jQuery plugin here: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pinch

Might be of some help

Comment: I think this is probably pretty close to what I need, but it doesn't actually have any releases to download. I'll see what I can find going forward in this direction though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Mobile Safari, then you will need a touch framework like jTouch to simplify things.

Natively, you should put your image and text inside a UIScrollView, and return the image view in the  the viewForZoomingInScrollView: (in the scroll view's delegates) to the image view.

Is that what you want?

Comment: It's a web based project, so I'll have to be using mobile Safari. If this was native I think this particular part would be easier.